# Connection refused: Server unavailable in Solace broker even after increase the Connection Scaling Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, solace

I am using Solace PubSub+ Software Message Broker Standard Edition from AWS Marketplace and I have increase the connection scaling Tier to 1000 connections using the [instructions here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/SW-Broker-Specific-Config/Configuring-SW-Broker-Conn-Scale-Tier-CLI.htm)

But I get  "Connection refused: Server unavailable" when I tried to connect the 101 publishing client. I have more than 100 connections if include 100 publishing clients with the subscription clients. It was not possible with to have more than 100 connections before the increase of connection scaling Tier to 1000 connections.

Any help is appreciated. I understand one will need the Enterprise Edition if one needs more than 1000 connections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the scaling tier from 100 to 1000, the number of client connections may still be limited to 100 by the following configurations:

1. The maximum number of client connections for the Message VPN.
2. The maximum number of MQTT client connections for the Message VPN.
3. The maximum number of client connections per client username.

To change 1, do the following:

```
solace1(configure)# message-vpn VPN_NAME
solace1(configure/message-vpn)# max-connections 1000
```

To change 2, do the following:

```
solace1(configure)# message-vpn VPN_NAME
solace1(configure/message-vpn)# service mqtt
solace1(configure/message-vpn/service/mqtt)# max-connections 1000
```

To change 3, do the following:

```
solace1(configure)# message-vpn VPN_NAME
solace1(configure)# client-profile CLIENT_USERNAME message-vpn VPN_NAME 
solace1(configure/client-profile)# max-connections-per-client-username 1000
```

Comment: Thanks, Leipo. I double checked show system and it shows 1000 max connection. There are 2 vcpu and 8.0GB ram. "Show stat client" shows 104 clients. 4 of them are my subscribers.